# Hosting nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have my own physical server in a datacenter.
I have experience in hosting IIS for production. And I never done it for nodejs and mongodb.
Would like to ask, is there any standard procedure I should follow when hosting both nodejs and mongodb in my server? Or should I just setup it like how I setup in my local machine?

Comment: you can configure to your liking your local machine and then replicate it on a vps, I recommend infranetworking